# Roslyn - search all documents in custom path

Tags: c#, roslyn

In my project I have documents with name: *.generated.cs. 
I would like to add them to list but only with directory "Sample" or "BestSample". 
I have a code:

```
var files = from project in solution.Projects
            from document in project.Documents
            where document.FilePath == "Sample" || document.FilePath =="BestSample"
            select document;
```

but this not work ;( 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The FilePath is a full path to the file, so you'd probably have to do something like Path.GetDirectoryName(document.FilePath).EndsWith("Sample") or the like. Just use your usual string/path manipulation APIs on it.